# Cartthrob Checkout PHP Errors

Tags: cartthrob, php-errors

Managed to checkout fine before switching email notifications on. After switching to "Log and send" I now get a number of PHP errors using Cartthrob 2.5 and EE 2.7.2

Has anyone had a similar issue and managed to resolve?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 483

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 484

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 483

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 484

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 483

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 484

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 483

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 484

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/damelin/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/damelin/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/damelin/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/damelin/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 414
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are some core functions in your EE version that aren't support anymore by your version of PHP.

You could upgrade EE to the latest version and hope this fixes the problem. If this doesn't help you should make a bug report.

If you want to solve the problem yourself, you can open up the files mentioned in the php errors and edit those.
What you need to do is remove the `e` at the end of the first parameter of `preg_replace`.

Like so:

```
preg_replace("/\%u([0-9A-F]{4,4})/e","'&#'.base_convert('\\1',16,10).';'", $str);
```

Becomes:

```
preg_replace("/\%u([0-9A-F]{4,4})/","'&#'.base_convert('\\1',16,10).';'", $str);
```